# Node js retrieve last record insert by timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have developed a rest service using Node JS and Express with Mongo DB.
I have developed a POST service with a specific query using or operator and the record output are more than one. 
I would like to retrieve only the last insert by timestamp field
This is my code

```
router.post('/sensor/storico', VerifyToken, function(req,res) {
Sensor.find({$or:[{"machineIdentifier": req.body.machineIdentifier}, {"tire": req.body.tire}]}, (err, sensors) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
    }
        res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Sensor', version: sensors}});
          });
      });
```

How i can filter the result and retrieve only the last record insert by timestamp field?

Thanks

Comment: What mongo/mongoose versions are you working on?

Comment: Also "timestamp" can mean several things; can you show some of your data and your mongoose schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using as follow:

First you can sort your results by using [sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort) method. The sort() method orders the documents in the result set then you can use [limit()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) method to specify the maximum number of documents the cursor will return.

```
router.post('/sensor/storico', VerifyToken, function(req,res) {
Sensor.find({$or:[{"machineIdentifier": req.body.machineIdentifier}, {"tire": req.body.tire}]}).sort({createdAt: -1}).limit(1).exec(function(err, sensors){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
    }
        res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Sensor', version: sensors}});
          });
      });
```